# Two separate switches ganged, each with own function, with one power line to the box

Tags: wiring

I want to keep one switch as-is (powers an on/off fireplace fan). The other to be a dimmer switch for a ceiling light.
I need help with how to wire the outlet so the dimmer will not affect the fan.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the breaker for that circuit and check the circuit is dead with a tester.

Use a wire nut or wago to connect two short wires to the hot wire from the panel.

Connect each of the short wires to a switch, one wire to a switch.

Each switch will have power and can control the fan and light.

This is for non smart, non three way switches, which I am assuming you are not using.

I am also assuming when you said outlet, you meant the boxes the switches are in.  You have power to the fan switch, so this should not affect any other part of the circuit.

Comment: Also use a Wago or wire nut to connect all three white wires to each other, but not to either switch.